# Postifx receives mail but won't send mail out

Tags: postfix

I literally have no idea what's going on. I can receive mail perfectly fine to my email but when i go to reply it will not send I just get a    Mail Delivery System email saying it couldn't deliver.

I haven't configured dovecot as I didnt think I needed it?
Any ideas thanks.

My main.cf: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cymlgkhnuxqagmi/maincf.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `main.cf` add `relayhost =smtp.some_mail_server.com`

This host can be `smtp` server of your provider

Restart `postfix` after this.

Comment: I no longer get a Mail Delivery System email but when the email is sent it vanishes into thin air, it's not delivered. I'm using mandrill SMTP.

Comment: You must enter valid maybe is better to say real `smtp` server name. You can view maillog in `/var/log/mail.log`.